# Лексико-грамматический разряд у собственных имен существительных

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, если имена собственные употреблены в значении нарицательных (Платонов, Невтонов), то они тоже относятся к конкретным? 
Приобретают ли такие имена существительные дополнительные значения во множественном числе?
И будет ли "земля" в данном контексте в форме единственного числа употребляться в значении собирательного, то есть приобретать обобщенно-собирательное значение?

*Может собственных Платонов и быстрых разумом Невтонов Российская земля рождать (Л.).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если имена собственные употреблены в значении нарицательных (Платонов, Невтонов),  они же не стали отвлечёнными, вещественными или собирательными. Это всё тот же предмет, к тому же он может теперь сочетаться с числительными: Ну, теперь у нас есть два своих Платона Российская земля - Россия(двое таких же умных, способных к философии, рассудительных, как Платон). Значит, это конкретные существительные.

```
 И будет ли "земля" в данном контексте в форме единственного числа
 употребляться в значении собирательного
```

Российская земля - это страна, а не сборище Платонов и Невтонов. Смысл, конечно, содержит некое собирательное значение (у нас целая страна героев, учёных и пр.), но грамматически это конкретное существительное, если б это было собирательное, оно было бы или в среднем роде (крестьянство, студенчество), или во множественном числе (кудри, финансы, село Дарковичи, земли такого-то государства). У нас же в единственном числе. Грамматическое значение не поменялось, хотя **отчасти и есть значение совокупной множественности**.